# ClassNotFoundException referencing hornetq specific stuff in JBoss AS 7

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, classloader, hornetq

I am trying to use JMS in a JBoss AS 7 application.  Publishing normal messages seems to work OK, however when I try to use hornetq specific features (to exclude duplicate messages), an exception is thrown.
This is the code:

```
om.setStringProperty(org.hornetq.api.core.Message.HDR_DUPLICATE_DETECTION_ID.toString(), application+rs.getString("stream")+ rs.getInt("site"));
```

And here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hornetq.api.core.Message from [Module "deployment.TestRestEasy.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:191)
org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:361)
org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:333)
org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:310)
org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:103)
sample.Processor.processStreamSite(Processor.java:82)
sample.Processor.processSitesForStream(Processor.java:63)
sample.Processor.process(Processor.java:55)
sample.HelloWorld.process(HelloWorld.java:31)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:140)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:255)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:220)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:209)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:519)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:496)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119)
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

I believe I have configured the standalone.xml configuration file correctly, as the standard JMS code works.  Is there anything special I need to do to access HornetQ specific features?

Update:
Was worried was related to RestEasy stuff I was using, so moved into standalone Servlet, but still had same issue.  Code and exception below

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
   try {
    Context ic = new InitialContext();

  QueueConnectionFactory qcf = (QueueConnectionFactory) ic.lookup("java:/ConnectionFactory");
  Queue q = (Queue) ic.lookup("queue/test");

  QueueConnection qc = qcf.createQueueConnection();
  QueueSession qsess = qc.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
  QueueSender qsend = qsess.createSender(q);

  ObjectMessage om = qsess.createObjectMessage();
  om.setObject((Serializable)new InboundDirectory("X", "Y", 9));
  om.setStringProperty(org.hornetq.api.core.Message.HDR_DUPLICATE_DETECTION_ID.toString(), "X");
  qsend.send(om);
  System.out.println("X");
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

And here is the exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hornetq.api.core.Message from [Module "deployment.TestRestEasy.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:191)
org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:361)
org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:333)
org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:310)
org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:103)
TestServlet.doPost(TestServlet.java:65)
TestServlet.doGet(TestServlet.java:46)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

Further update:
Got it working by using the String value instead, but I don't think that is ideal, the property key is not guaranteed that string forever.

```
om.setStringProperty("_HQ_DUPL_ID", "X:Y:9");
```

Any idea the proper way to do it?

Update:  Thanks @Vadzim for pointing me in the right direction.  For anybody else struggling with this specific problem I updated the Manifest.MF as follows:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: 
Dependencies: org.hornetq
```

Note, (as I struggled with this for a while), the parsing of this file is very 'fragile'.  The Space after the 'Class-Path:' entry line is essential.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classloading model changed in JBoss 7. It hides much stuff that's not explicitly declared.

You have to get familar with these links:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Developer+Guide#DeveloperGuide-HowtoresolveClassNotFoundExceptionsandNoCLassDefFoundErrors

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks.  Pointed me in the right direction, but still left me a bit of work to do.

Comment: You are welcome. Those links provide much useful info to help you with migration. It's worth reading anyway. Quick answer could prevent you from doing it. :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the hornetq-client should be exposed to the HOrnetQ module.

Maybe you should talk to AS7 guys through their forum.. or maybe raise an issue on jira.jboss.org for the AS7 project.. but I believe you are required to talk on the forums first.